# How to pass input value to form onSubmit without using state in component that renders multiple forms?

Tags: forms, reactjs, input

This is a bit of a longwinded problem and giving me a ton of headache to solve.

I'm making a voting app. On the page there will be a list of polls on which you can vote. Each poll is a form consisting of input radio buttons representing the different options available for that poll.

What I was doing previously was saving the option you choose to component state in `this.state.value` and then passing it as an argument to an action creator when the form is submitted.

Problem with this approach is that if I click an option of one poll, and then click submit on another poll, I've actually submitted the wrong option to the wrong poll.

Is there a way to pass input value to form `onSubmit` without storing it in component state?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Loading from '../Loading';

class MyPolls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      skip: 0,
      isLoading: true,
      isLoadingMore: false,
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMyPolls(this.state.skip)
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
            skip: this.state.skip + 4,
            isLoading: false
          });
        }, 1000);
      });
  }

  sumVotes(acc, cur) {
    return acc.votes + cur.votes
  }

  loadMore(skip) {
    this.setState({ isLoadingMore: true });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.fetchMyPolls(skip)
        .then(() => {
          const nextSkip = this.state.skip + 4;
          this.setState({
            skip: nextSkip,
            isLoadingMore: false
          });
        });
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleSubmit(title, e) {
    // console.log(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    const vote = {
      title,
      option: this.state.value
    };

    console.log(vote)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  renderPolls() {
    return this.props.polls.map(poll => {
      return (
        <div
          className='card'
          key={poll._id}
          style={{ width: '350px', height: '400px' }}>
          <div className='card-content'>
            <span className='card-title'>{poll.title}</span>
            <p>
              Total votes: {poll.options.reduce((acc, cur) => { return acc + cur.votes }, 0)}
            </p>
            <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(poll.title, e)}>
              {poll.options.map(option => {
                return (
                  <p key={option._id}>
                    <input
                      name={poll.title}
                      className='with-gap'
                      type='radio'
                      id={option._id}
                      value={option.option}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={option._id}>
                      {option.option}
                    </label>
                  </p>
                )
              })}

              <button
                type='text'
                className='activator teal btn waves-effect waves-light'
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: '10%',
                  transform: 'translateX(-50%)'
                }}
                >
                Submit
                <i className='material-icons right'>
                  send
                </i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className='card-reveal'>
            <span className='card-title'>{poll.title}
              <i className='material-icons right'>close</i>
            </span>
            <p>
              dsfasfasdf
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='center-align container'>
        <h2>My Polls</h2>
        {this.state.isLoading ? <Loading size='big' /> :
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center'
          }}>
          {this.renderPolls()}
        </div>}
        <div className='row'>
          {this.state.isLoadingMore ? <Loading size='small' /> :
          <button
            className='btn red lighten-2 wave-effect waves-light' onClick={() => this.loadMore(this.state.skip)}>
            Load More
          </button>}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ polls }) {
  return { polls }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyPolls);
```

App demo: https://voting-app-drhectapus.herokuapp.com/
(use `riverfish@gmail.com` and password `123` to login)

Github repo: https://github.com/drhectapus/voting-app

I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: A typical solution to your problem would be to create a `<Poll/>` component class (with independent `state` and an `onSubmit()`) to render for each `Poll`.

Comment: I knew there was an easy solution i was overlooking. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more "React'ish" pattern would be to break it down to more components.
a `Poll` is a component, a `PollOption` could be a component as well.
Where each can handle the state internally.

This will allow you to keep global state in your `App` or some other state manager like `redux` that will hold all of your polls and each can reference to the selected option (id).

Another thing worth pointing, is that you tend to pass a new function reference on each `render` call.
For example:

```
onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(poll.title, e)}
```

This is considered as bad practice because you can interfere with the [Reconciliation and The Diffing Algorithm of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

When you break it down to components that each can fire back a callback with its 
props, then you don't need to pass the handler this way.

Here is a small example with your data:

```js
const pollsFromServer = [
  {
    _id: "5a0d308a70f4b10014994490",
    title: "Cat or Dog",
    _user: "59f21388843e737de3738a3a",
    __v: 0,
    dateCreated: "2017-11-16T06:30:34.855Z",
    options: [
      { option: "Cat", _id: "5a0d308a70f4b10014994492", votes: 0 },
      { option: "Dog", _id: "5a0d308a70f4b10014994491", votes: 0 }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5a0c7941e655c22b8cce43d7",
    title: "Blonde or Brunette?",
    _user: "59f21388843e737de3738a3a",
    __v: 0,
    dateCreated: "2017-11-15T17:28:33.909Z",
    options: [
      { option: "Blonde", _id: "5a0c7941e655c22b8cce43d9", votes: 0 },
      { option: "Brunette", _id: "5a0c7941e655c22b8cce43d8", votes: 0 }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5a0c7924e655c22b8cce43d4",
    title: "Coke or Pepsi",
    _user: "59f21388843e737de3738a3a",
    __v: 0,
    dateCreated: "2017-11-15T17:28:04.119Z",
    options: [
      { option: "Coke", _id: "5a0c7924e655c22b8cce43d6", votes: 0 },
      { option: "Pepsi", _id: "5a0c7924e655c22b8cce43d5", votes: 0 }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "5a0c78c2e655c22b8cce43d0",
    title: "Favourite german car?",
    _user: "59f21388843e737de3738a3a",
    __v: 0,
    dateCreated: "2017-11-15T17:26:26.724Z",
    options: [
      { option: "BMW", _id: "5a0c78c2e655c22b8cce43d3", votes: 0 },
      { option: "Mercedes", _id: "5a0c78c2e655c22b8cce43d2", votes: 0 },
      { option: "Audi", _id: "5a0c78c2e655c22b8cce43d1", votes: 0 }
    ]
  }
];

class Poll extends React.Component {

  onSubmit = optionId => {
    const { pollId, onSubmit } = this.props;
    onSubmit(pollId, optionId);
  };

  render() {
    const { title, options, selectedOption } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <ul>
          {options.map((o, i) => {
            return (
              <PollOption
                isSelected={selectedOption === o._id}
                onClick={this.onSubmit}
                name={o.option}
                optionId={o._id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PollOption extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    const { optionId, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(optionId);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, isSelected } = this.props;
    const selectedClass = isSelected ? "selected" : '';
    return (
      <li
        className={`poll-option ${selectedClass}`}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        {name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      polls: pollsFromServer,
      submittedPolls: []
    };
  }

  onPollSubmit = (pollId, optionId) => {
    this.setState({
      submittedPolls: {
        ...this.state.submittedPolls,
        [pollId]: optionId
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { polls, submittedPolls } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {polls.map((p, i) => {
          const selectedPoll = submittedPolls[p._id];
          return (
            <Poll
              selectedOption={selectedPoll}
              pollId={p._id}
              onSubmit={this.onPollSubmit}
              title={p.title}
              options={p.options}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.poll-option{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #333;
  padding: 15px;
}
.selected{
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```